# PHP Exeption object error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpbb3

Well the subject says most of it. I have a javascript function that uses an Ajax call, using POST, and returns an array created by a php sql query. Well... it's supposed to at least. I can get the ajax to return a very simple php echo. When I add the rest of the code necessary to build my db connect, even without trying to pass the array, I start to get an Exception Object, 503 error.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
function updateYears(pageLoaded) {
  var yearSelect = document.getElementById("vehicle_year");
  var makeSelect = document.getElementById("vehicle_make");
  var modelSelect = document.getElementById("vehicle_model");

  $('#vehicle_year').html('');

  var $data = [];

  $.ajax({ url: '/new.php',
      data: {action: 'test'},
      type: 'post',
      success:function(result)//we got the response
      {
        alert(result);
      },
      error:function(exception){alert('Exception:'+exception);}
  });

  return false;

}
```

**PHP**

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

$db = new $sql_db();

$db->sql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbname, $dbport);

// We do not need this any longer, unset for safety purposes
unset($dbpasswd);

if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    switch($action) {
        case 'get_vehicle_makes' :
            get_vehicle_makes();
            break;
        case 'get_vehicle_models' :
            get_vehicle_models();
            break;
        case 'test' :
            get_vehicle_years();
            break;
    }
}
//Populate a unique list of vehicle years - this only runs on page load
//The vehicle years list will always be the same regardless of make or model  - block_var = "vehicle_years"
function get_vehicle_years()
{
    echo ("good job");
    exit;
}
```

Now, there's a lot going on in the PHP file, but I am really just trying to `echo ("test");` for right now. If I remove the code in the PHP file that is between, `define('IN_PHPBB', true);` and `unset($dbpasswd);`, it works, so I know there is something wrong with the db connection code. The include statements are fine, because I don't get an error saying the file doesn't exist. The connection credential variables are also fine, because I get those from the config.php file that's included. I'm at a loss, and could really use some help.

Comment: Good places to investigate are your _apache_, _php_ and _mysql_ log files (if you're running Linux you can find them in the /var/log folder).

You can also ask php to print more debug information by adding the following lines to your script :
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: where at in my php would I add those lines?

Comment: At the beginning of the script.

Comment: I'm not a user of phpbb so it's a little hard to guess, but you may be missing an include to use the database such as it's done on [this page](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Dbal.sql_connect).

I don't see any include of the `db` folder in the [`common.php`](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/c571d99c0f4108ec9136b601c9a57b4878597470/phpBB/common.php) file.

But again, more logging is necessary to really identify the problem..

Comment: `require($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/db/' . $dbms . '.' . $phpEx);` is inside common.php which gets the db classes needed. `common.php` also has the connection string `$db->sql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbname, $dbport, false, defined('PHPBB_DB_NEW_LINK') ? PHPBB_DB_NEW_LINK : false);` so I shouldn't have to try to connect at all; just include `common.php`. Nothing is working though. There are plenty of other php files that connect to the db to run queries, and I'm not really doing anything much different, except that I'm running my php from an Ajax call.